# Laravel 5.2 Auth Scaffolding Reset Password Email Not Firing - Is it queued?

Tags: php, laravel, email

Ok so I am currently using Mandrill for email.
I have assumed this is *not* the issue. This test route, for example fires fine.

```
 public function email($emailAddress){
        $data = array(
            'email'     => $emailAddress,
            'name'      => 'Test Name'
            );
        $result = Mail::queue('emails.test', $data, function ($message) use ($data){
            $message->from(Config::get('settings.contact_form_from.address'), Config::get('settings.contact_form_from.name'));
            $message->sender(Config::get('settings.contact_form_from.address'), Config::get('settings.contact_form_from.name'));
            $message->to($data['email'], $data['name']);
            $message->subject('Test email to: ' . $data['email']);
        });
        return $this->response($result);
    }
```

This is using the `queue` function. If adjusted to `Mail::send()` also work's fine. Thus all my queue handlers and mail env variables are working fine. (I can see both these emails in Mandrill).

So my issue is the the *password reset* functionality which I have installed using the Laravel 5.2 Auth Scaffolding.

So, the route etc all works fine - just no email sends.

It correctly identifies if the user does/doesn't exist (displays the correct error message).

So then I have a look through source code and got slightly lost, help is needed!

If i look in here... `...Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetPasswords.php` I can see this method.

public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateSendResetLinkEmail($request);

```
$broker = $this->getBroker();

$response = Password::broker($broker)->sendResetLink(
    $this->getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials($request),
    $this->resetEmailBuilder()
);
switch ($response) {
    case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
        return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response);
    case Password::INVALID_USER:
    default:
        return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response);
}
```

}

If I break at `$response` I am getting response that it is sent correctly. So I assume it is something to do with  `Password::broker` section, the code here completely looses me.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have default from email settings in `config/mail.php`?

```
 'from' => [
   'address' => 'info@domain.tld',
   'name' => 'My site',
 ],
```

And is this domain in your Mandrill whitelisted domains?

Comment: Thank you! I have looked over so much stuff and not even seen this! It was set to null, wish it threw an error!